# Jenkins "run only if build succeeds" still runs for unsuccessful builds

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, build-automation

I'am using Jenkins for continuous integration and I have some projects having upstream and downstream build connections. I have selected `Run only if build succeeds` in each project's configuration. However, the post-build step is still getting triggered for unstable builds. Jenkins version is 1.480.3 . I wonder if is there anyone having a similar experience.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the bug tracker or release notes? This may be a bug that has been fixed in a more recent version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an existing issue in Jenkins 1.480.3. It got resolved 1.509.1. The link of jira is as  follows.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14102