# Jenkins post-build step ignores "Run only if build succeeds" option

Tags: maven, jenkins

Simply, I have some Jenkins Maven projects each with a Post Step set to "Run only if build succeeds." Earlier today, the main Build Step clearly failed, yet Jenkins proceeded to run the Post Step that was configured to "Run only if build succeeds." It did something like fail to run tests, but then commit and push code.

As I promised before this edit, here is a minimal example with an empty workspace and no SCM steps:

[image: Failing Maven step, Post Step that should not run]

```
Started by user Jason Young
Building remotely on *** in workspace /var/jenkins/workspace/PoC-buildFailurePostSteps-Maven
Parsing POMs
[PoC-buildFailurePostSteps-Maven] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins5633688611993290464.sh
+ echo 'This is the Post Step. Should not run.'
This is the Post Step. Should not run.
ERROR: No such file /var/jenkins/workspace/PoC-buildFailurePostSteps-Maven/pom.xml
Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?
Finished: FAILURE
```

The Maven step failure is exactly what we expect, but the build should not run that Post Step in the process. What could I have done wrong?

This defect was introduced in Jenkins and [fixed in 1.509.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17827584/5447019), but appears to be back in 2.60.2 (what I'm using).

I'm using Maven Integration plugin v. 2.17.

Comment: it's not a jenkins, it's a maven plugins issue. Try to downgrade the maven integration plugin

Comment: @YuriG. You must be advising me to downgrade https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin which has defect https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22659 which I'm experiencing. Do you know what version(s) are affected by this defect / which ones are fine?

Comment: That JIRA link appears to be for Jenkins, not specific to the plugin, but it is the sight linked to from the plugin's page.

Comment: @YuriG. any links or other info you may have, especially pertaining the conclusion that it's a maven plugin issue, would be valuable.